# How can i detect network changes in my ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

i want to check for network connectivity in my ionic app, but its not working.
Here's the code

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
    let connectSubscription=this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
        console.log(2)
        console.log('live network was disconnected :-(');
    });
    connectSubscription.unsubscribe();
    let disconnectSubscription=this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
        console.log(4)
        console.log('live network connected!');         
    });
    disconnectSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

I want to know when my network is online and when the network does offline i should know but this code does noting, it outputs noting to the console, i am using the latest ionic 6.9

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is better to check additional the network-type
In general do the following:

- implement it as a service
- inject the service in the module

NetworkService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NetworkService{

    constructor(public network: Network) {

    }

    checkOnlineStat(){
          if (this.network.type === 'none'){
          return "offline";
    
    
        }else if(this.network.type === 'wifi'){
          return "online";
 
        }
    }

}
```

component.ts:

```
   constructor(public networkSrv: NetworkService) {}

public onViewDidLoad() {
  if (networkSrv.checkOnlineStat === 'online') {
     // online
  }
}
```

Use the Service where you need it. You can generate a new service by cli.

Comment: how can i detect when the network goes off or comes in when the user is using the app